# Bootstrap3 Datetimepicker issues: missing icon, how to use Date() function?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, datetimepicker

I'm using the Bootstrap3 Datetimepicker as packaged for Meteor on this site:

https://github.com/tsega/meteor-bootstrap3-datetimepicker

I have two problems.

1) there is no calendar icon on the button you click to open the calendar.

2) The date() function fails with an error: "Exception in template helper: TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker(...).date is not a function".

Here's what I included via the command line:

```
meteor add jquery
meteor add mrt:moment
meteor add twbs:bootstrap 
meteor add tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker
```

It is possible these weren't the right packages, but they did get it basically working...

I've followed the example on the author's page. Here's my JavaScript:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.say_when.onRendered(function() {
    this.$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    }).on('dp.change', function(e){
      Session.set("selected", e.date.format());
    });
  });

  Template.say_when.helpers({
    // Works
    show_date: function(){
      return Session.get("selected");
    },
    // Fails
    test: function(){
      var date = $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker().date();
      console.log("Date from picker: " + date);
    }
  });
}
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>datetimepicker</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Bootstrap3 Datetimepicker in Meteor</h1>

  {{> say_when}}
</body>

<template name="say_when">
  <div class="input-group datetimepicker">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    <input class="set-due-date form-control" type="text"/>
  </div>

  <p>{{show_date}}</p>
  <p>{{test}}</p>
</template>
```

1) Is there something else I need to add in order to get the calendar icon?

2) How can I make the date() function work?

Answer (score 0):

check out the same project I have made.

will post the answer soon

https://github.com/kokaqux/posttracker

Comment: My question is how can I use the **date()** method?

In your project I think you got the current value of the input using jQuery, with this code:

time: $('#datetimepicker').val()

I would like to use the component's method instead of relying on knowing how the HTML is structured, and also I would like to be able to use other methods as described in the document.

I am probably being dumb but I just can't figure out how to make any of the methods work!